# Append all list items only target last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jquery function to (1st)add elements into default unordered list(animal), and (2nd)show/hide 'deletebutton' on the list items(including the new menu list items) when click on the 'editBtn'. I want to select ALL list items but it only shows onto the last item..

JS

```
$(function() {
    var cat = $('<li><a href="#" class="">Cat</a></li>');
    var dog = $('<li><a href="#" class="">Dog</a></li>');
    var lion = $('<li><a href="#" class="">Lion</a></li></li>');
    var deletebutton = $('<input class="delBtn" type="submit" value="delete"/>');

    $('ul#animal li').append(deletebutton);

    $('#editBtn').click(function(){
        deletebutton.toggle();
    });     

    //limit to one click event
    $('#addCat').one("click", function() {
        $(cat).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('#addDog').one("click", function() {
        $(dog).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('#addLion').one("click", function() {
        $(lion).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">                                    
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addCat">AddCat&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addDog">AddDog&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>       
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addLion">AddLion</a> 
</div>
<br />
<br />

<div>
    <a href="#" id="editBtn">Edit Button</a>
</div>    

<div class="screen">
    <ul id="animal">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Bird</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Snake</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">fish</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
}
.screen{
    background-color: grey;
}
.delBtn{
    display:none;
}
```

jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Ne63M/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne63M/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your variable declaration to

```
var deletebutton = '<input class="delBtn" type="submit" value="delete"/>';
```

As it will append a new input to each item, and then change the click event to:

```
$('#editBtn').click(function(){
    $(".delBtn").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to clone the `deletebutton`, otherwise the reference points to the same instances:

`$('ul#animal li').append(deletebutton.clone());`

Then you can refer to them by class instead of the variable:

`$('.delBtn'). //stuff`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne63M/2/)

Comment: thanks! but how can I target all list including the added menu items?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Target them how? They'd be in the dom, so a selector like `li` would capture them.

Comment: hmm.. the deletebutton won't show on the added menu list but only show on the default list.. could you try on your Fiddle?

Comment: You're only adding the delete button to the list items on page load: `$('ul#animal li').append(deletebutton.clone());` - you need to append it manually to the new list items when you're adding them.